# Why was this answer deleted for moderation purposes? What am I not seeing here?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation

Note:  this isn't my answer, but it was a competing answer to a question.

Is there any specific reason that [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41411475/1079354) was deleted by a moderator?  I can't identify anything that would warrant its immediate mod-related removal.

(Image for <10K users with moderator name removed)

[image]

Comment: I presume a mistake.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  That's what I'm thinking...

Comment: I feel left out...

Comment: @Daniel:  It happens sometimes that I forget this; I've provided a redacted screenshot.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The answer was deleted by the author's request because they couldn't delete it through the mobile app.<sup>1</sup> This was indicated in a flag, but in some cases it'll be made obvious to you either by the author frantically commenting on their answer asking for help, or better yet, the author straight-up vandalizing their answer.

I agree that we should make it clear to you guys when we're deleting answers that are otherwise not problematic (which I've been doing when deleting accepted answers). Right now there isn't any functionality to either automate this or otherwise make it an official deletion reason; we have to leave a comment manually, though this is made significantly less troublesome by the fact that moderators can leave new comments on deleted posts after the fact.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>I've ranted at length about this omission to the other mods and the staff, but apparently none of them thinks this is a problem, and some of the other mods have even *declined* such flags telling users to use a browser to delete their answers (gee, I wonder why we even have an app then).</sub>

Comment: I won't deny that this is definitely one of the biggest limitations with the app.  Okay then, I'm satisfied with this answer.  Thanks! :)

Comment: If any lurkers want (like me) to support BoltClock in his rants about this gaping hole in the app, here's a feature request to support: [*Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder funny, you can't vote to reopen either...

Comment: The mobile site is WAY better than the app.

Comment: And while we're on the subject of the app, at least on iOS, trying to edit long titles is an exercise in frustration/futility.  And … oh, maybe this belongs somewhere else…

Answer (score 13):

Occasionally a moderator deletes an answer at the author's request, when the author can't do it themselves (for example, if it is the accepted answer).

I don't know if that happened here, but it does result in moderator deletion of technical answers that aren't spammy or plagiarized, and the it doesn't leave any trail that's publicly viewable, even 10k users can't see the "flag for moderator attention" message, or even that there was a flag.

Comment: That's what happened here. There's a flag on the answer requesting deletion because the OP was unable to do it on their own through the app.

Comment: @Adam: I wonder if it would be worth giving you a checkbox that would do two things: (1) suffix the deletion message with "at author's request" and (2) permit the author to edit and undelete

Comment: Gut feel says "it's too edge-casey to introduce a checkbox on every deletion". Having said that, if it were off by default, replacing the browser-based confirmation dialog with a custom one isn't *that* expensive either. The author can always post a new answer instead of editing/undeleting, too. I don't think there'd be a big win here personally, but I can see some potential.